# My self made slider doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I have a problem with my self made image slider, i get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Edit: I have called all images like this: img1, img2, img3 etc with extension .jpg

this is my javascript code:

```
     // JavaScript Document
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 3;


window.setInterval(function slideA(x) 
{
    var Image = document.getElementById('img');
    imagecount = imagecount + x;
    if(imagecount > total) { imagecount = 1; }
    if(imagecount < 1) { imagecount = total; }
    Image.src = "images_slider/img" + imagecount + ".jpeg";
}, 5000);

function init() 
{
    slideA();
}

window.onload = init;


<div id="LandingImage">
    <img src="../images/landingimage.png" alt="LandingImage" width="100%"         height="100%"  />  
    </div>
```

Can someone help me with this? 
Thanks!

Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to iterate through a list of images by changing the source of an image.  If so, refer to the following JS fiddle for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hqq1k2Lk/3/

I made a few changes, so let's go through it together.

```
// JavaScript Document
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 3;


function slideA()
{
    //slideA starts the interval
    window.setInterval(function(){
        var myImage = document.getElementById('LandingImage');
        imagecount++;
        if(imagecount > total) { imagecount = 1; }
        if(imagecount < 1) { imagecount = total; }
        myImage.src = "images_slider/img" + imagecount + ".jpeg";            
    }, 5000);
}

function init() 
{
    slideA();
}

window.onload = init();
```

First, I moved your function call slideA outside the interval.  Thus calling `slideA();` will start the interval.

Next, I moved your ID LandingImage to the img element itself, so we can get the image from the DOM using `document.getElementById('LandingImage');`

Since you need to keep track of what image you're on, I elected to use imagecount as your counter.  You can increment a number by 1 by using ++ such as `imagecount++;`

As others have pointed out Image is a protected object name in Javascript, so I renamed your variable to `myImage`

Lastly, in order to start the whole process, I added a function call to your window onload event.  Whenever you want to call a function, remember to use ()

```
window.onload = init();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend! But the problem is fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Your html element does not have an id of `img`, you appear to be trying to select the tag name.

I also suggest not using `Image` as the variable name, since `Image` is an object name in JavaScript.

```
<img src="../images/landingimage.png" alt="LandingImage" width="100%" height="100%" id="img" /> <!-- id at the end, was missing -->
```

Comment: Thanks! It does something more now. But i do get this error now: GET file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Portfolio_WP_22/images_slider/imgNaN.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: x is left undefined in your interval, thus 1 + undefined = NaN.

Comment: @Vaune_X How can i fix this problem? This is my first javascript self made code, I'm still a rookie..

Comment: @Vaune_X I tried to make a: Var x; in the top of my js file.

Comment: I assume you are attempting to cycle through a list of available images by incrementing a counter with each interval, yes?  If so, then remove the x from your function, and instead increment imagecount using imagecount++;

Comment: @Vaune_X Thanks a lot my friend! + 1000

Answer (score 0):

As another poster mentioned, do not use `Image` as your variable name.

To access the `src` attribute of the element, you use `element.setAttribute('src', 'insert src here')` not `element.src`.

Comment: Hello, I have changed the variable name to something else. But I now get this error: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Portfolio_WP_22/images_slider/imgNaN.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: The `NaN` in the name means that your iteration variable is coming back not a number. Looking at your code, where is `x` defined?